# Back/Forward Firefox navigation with arrow keys except in input

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, plugins

I've mapped my left/right arrow keyboard keys in Firefox to navigate back/forward in the browser history (old Opera habit).

This works perfectly except when I'm entering data into input fields. I keep using the back arrow key to navigate the input field and end up taking myself back one page.

Are there any options that will:

1. Allow me to specifically disable shortcuts if the cursor is in the input fields? OR
2. A specific plugin which will map these arrow keys to back/forward but will restore the default behavior on these keys when the cursor is in the input fields?

Comment: Why don't you just use Alt + left/right to move back/forwards? This is standard in most browsers I've used.

Comment: I second Lee Taylor's answer. It seems hard coded into Firefox that backspace does not go back when in a text field. It is probably possible that an extension could be written that takes where your cursor is into context however it doesn't look like one exists. I think you're making your life a bit complicated by doing it that way. I also suggest installing this extension - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/ - and maybe changing it to control-arrow ..  which is closer than alt-arrow. It shouldn't be too different than what you're use to.

Comment: Using left/right keys is just an old habit. Haven't been able to switch to Alt + left/right for some reason. Here's to hoping there's an option out there.